# Write Picture to mp3 File ID3.NET Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, id3

I'm working in my new app to modify the ID3 Tags.

I can edit title,album and artists but I can't modify the Pictures.

Here is my small code

```
IList<string> artists = new List<string> { "test artist" };
               tag.Title.Value = "my test";
               tag.Album.Value = "album test";
               tag.Artists.Value.Add("test artist");
               tag.Pictures.Add(new Id3.Frames.PictureFrame 
               {
                   PictureData = array,
                   PictureType = Id3.Frames.PictureType.Media,
                   MimeType = "image/jpeg"
               });
               stream.WriteTag(tag, 1, 0, WriteConflictAction.Replace);
               stream.Dispose();
```

When I open the mp3 file I can't see the image while it's playing.

Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stream.WriteTag(tag, 1, 0, WriteConflictAction.Replace);
```

`1` represents the major and `0` the minor ID3 version. Since media types such as pictures/images are not implemented in version 1, you'll need to use at least version 2. (2.3 being the most popular version used in ID3 tagging libraries and 2.4 being the newest version released in 2000)

```
stream.WriteTag(tag, 2, 3, WriteConflictAction.Replace);
```

will resolve your issue. Please note that you also need to create an `Idv23Tag` when applying the code above:

`var tag = new Id3v23Tag();`

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3 for more information.